# Migrating mounted ntfs folders to another installation

Tags: mount, ntfs

I'm using server 2012 r2 + drivepool + jbod 4u60, the drives are mounted to 20ish ntfs mount folders, and now i want to migrate to another machine with better specs.
The idea is just to swap the sas card and then i hope i dont have to remount the drives again because i want to minimize downtime.
Is there anyway to copy these mount folders to the new machine? Or do i have to recreate and re-mount them again one by one? Cause when i tried to copy them, its actually copying the entire drive...

Edit : Well i found out the registry location,

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\LOCALMOF\

I'm gonna export and import this key and see if it works

Comment: Edit : well it doesn't work, even though i already create the mounted folders